# Continuous Linear Transformation Maps Open Set to Bounded Set

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I want to prove that if a linear transformation maps some nonvoid open set of the domain space to a bounded set in the range space, then it is continuous.

I tried to prove by contradiction that suppose $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is not continuous, then $\exists\epsilon_0>0,\forall\delta>0\text{ such that }||Tx-Ty||\geq\epsilon_0\text{ yet }||x-y||<\delta $

Let $U\subset X$ be a nonvoid open set, $\forall x\in U,\exists\delta_x>0\text{ such that } y\in U \text{ if } ||x-y||<\delta_x$. So, $||Tx-Ty||\geq \epsilon_0$

I am not sure if this is the correct approach or how to proceed from here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Randall This is a question from Cheney's Analysis for Applies Math, the problem does not specify what exactly $X$ and $Y$ are

Comment: I would imagine you show continuity at $0$ by translating something around, then make use of boundedness.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are normed vector spaces, as this seems the most likely interpretation to me. Let $U$ be the open domain. As it is non-empty there exists an $z\in U$ and $0<r\leq 1$ such that the closed ball $\bar B(z;r)\subset U$. Define $C=\sup_{x\in U} \|Tx\|_Y$, which exists and is finite by assumption. Any $x\in \partial \bar B(z;r)$ can be written as $x=z+r u$, where $\|u\|=1$, and conversely, for every $u$ with $\|u\|=1$, $z+ru\in \partial \bar B(z;r)$. Thus, for any $u$ with $\|u\|=1$, we have
$$C\geq \|Tx\|\geq\|T(ru)\|-\|Tz\|,$$
allowing us to conclude that
$$\sup_{\|u\|=1} \|Tu\|\leq 2C/r.$$
Thus $T$ is a bounded linear operator, so continuous.